# Passport details

Tags: uk, uk-citizens

My name and address, passport number, place and date of birth were on a camping carnet which has been stolen along with my purse. What do I need to do? Should I report my passport as lost even though I still have that in my possession?

Comment: @Diane There are some identity theft prevention measures that you should consider taking https://ico.org.uk/your-data-matters/identity-theft/